# Applying aggregate function on columns of Pandas pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I generated the following pivot table via taking maximum of values in `Z` column:

```
   val
X   x1     x2
Y   y1  y2 y1  y2
ID
a    9   1  5  11
b    8  10  7   6
```

After taking max on `Z` values, I need to report `mean(y1,y2)`. The desired table is:

```
    val
X    x1          x2
Y    mean(y1,y2) mean(y1,y2)
ID
a    5           8
b    9           6.5
```

How can I achieve this using pandas?

My MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_table('data.txt')
pv=data.pivot_table(index=['ID'], columns=['X','Y'], values=['val'], aggfunc=np.max )
print pv
```

`data.txt`:

```
ID  X   Y   Z   val
a   x1  y2  z1  1
b   x1  y1  z2  2
a   x2  y2  z2  3
a   x1  y1  z4  4
a   x2  y1  z1  5
b   x2  y2  z3  6
b   x2  y1  z2  7
b   x1  y1  z3  8
a   x1  y1  z3  9
b   x1  y2  z3  10
a   x2  y2  z2  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `level` param and `axis` to calc the [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html#pandas.DataFrame.mean) for the desired axis level:

```
In [142]:
pv.mean(level='X', axis=1)

Out[142]:
X   x1   x2
ID         
a    5  8.0
b    9  6.5
```